What are the integer solutions to $x^4+2y^4=3z^4$?
This equation has the obvious integer solution $(x,y,z)=(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1)$. By Faltings's theorem, the equation has finitely many primitive integer solutions (those with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$).
What is the complete set of non-trivial primitive integer solutions (those with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ and $xyz \neq 0$) to this equation?
This is the equation of the form
$$
ax^4+by^4=cz^4,
$$
where $a,b,c$ are positive integer coefficients, with smallest value $a+b+c$ for which the problem of describing all integer solutions to the equation appears to be open.
The general equation can be reduced to the three elliptic curves
$$
ax^2+by^4=cz^4, \quad ax^4+by^2=cz^4, \quad ax^4+by^4=cz^2.
$$
If one of these curves has rank $0$, then the question is easy. Triple $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$ is the smallest triple for which the three elliptic curves have positive rank, therefore there are infinitely many solutions and it is not easy to check whether in one of these solutions the corresponding variable is a perfect square.
Also, the existence of the solution $(\pm1, \pm1, \pm1)$ implies that the standard version of the Mordell-Weil sieve will give no contradiction modulo any prime.
The problem of whether an integer solution exists to the general equation with $a+b+c<39$ has been solved in [1] but the problem for describing all integer solutions was not investigated.
[1] B. Grechuk. Polynomial Diophantine Equations: A Systematic Approach. Springer International Publishing, 2024. URL https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rj8eEQAAQBAJ.

Of course you can scale the solutions by any integer. Faltings's theorem implies that this equation will have finitely many solutions up to scaling. That's probably about all you can say from just general principles.

Have you done any computation to see whether there are any other small solutions, Ashleigh?

it's a genus 3 curve with a big automorphisms group (at the very least you have $\langle x\mapsto ix, y\mapsto iy\rangle$). Specifically you have (at least) three elliptic quotients, so you can start by finding the rational points on these curves.

I have edited the question to make it clearer that I am looking for the complete set of primitive solutions. I have not found any other small solutions (searching for $|x| \neq |y|$, $xyz \neq 0$ and $|z| \leq 10^4$).

@DavidLehavi The three curves have positive rank and I have updated the question  accordingly.

Let $C : x^{4} + 2y^{4} = 3z^{4}$. Then $C(\mathbb{Q}) = \{ (\pm 1 : \pm 1 : 1) \}$. In particular, the only coprime solutions to the equation are those mentioned by the OP.
Rewrite the equation for $C$ in the form
$$
  (2x^{2} - 4y^{2} + 6z^{2}) (-x^{2} + 2y^{2} + 3z^{2}) = (2x^{2} + 2y^{2})^{2}.
$$
(This identity comes from the fact that $C$ has unramified double covers, which can be obtained by letting $\varphi : C \to E$ be one of the maps to an elliptic curve, and letting $R = \varphi^{-1}((0,0)) - \varphi^{-1}(\infty)$, where $(0,0)$ is a point of order $2$ on $E$. This $R$ is a non-principal degree zero divisor on $C$ and $2R$ is principal. If $f \in \mathbb{Q}(C)$ with ${\rm div}(f) = 2R$, then we can obtain an unramified double cover by adding the equation $w^{2} = f$ to that of $C$.)
If we have a point $(x : y : z)$ on $C$ where $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$, then there must be some squarefree $\delta$ so that $2x^{2} - 4y^{2} + 6z^{2}$ and $-x^{2} + 2y^{2} + 3z^{2}$ are both $\delta$ times a square. This leads to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
  2x^{2} - 4y^{2} + 6z^{2} &= \delta r^{2}\\
  2x^{2} + 2y^{2} &= \delta rs\\
  -x^{2} + 2y^{2} + 3z^{2} &= \delta s^{2}.
\end{align*}
A calculation shows that $\delta \in \{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 6 \}$. The only such equation that has points in $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_{3}$ is $\delta = 1$. Let $D$ be the genus $5$ curve whose equations are above with $\delta = 1$. The original claim is therefore equivalent to the statement that
$D(\mathbb{Q}) = \{ (\pm 1/2 : \pm 1/2 : \pm 1/2 : 1 : 1) \}$.
The Prym variety of $C$ is the two-dimensional factor of ${\rm Jac}(D)$ that is "new" (it does not come from ${\rm Jac}(C)$). In the paper The arithmetic of Prym varieties in genus 3 (published in Compositio in 2008), Nils Bruin gives a formula for a genus $2$ hyperelliptic curve whose Jacobian is isomorphic to the Prym variety. Applying his work in this case shows that the rank of the Prym variety is $1$, and so the Chabauty-Coleman method should apply to $D$ (even though it did not apply to $C$).
To explicitly handle the two-dimensional Prym, we take the equations for $D$ and solve for $x^{2}$, $y^{2}$ and $z^{2}$ and get
\begin{align*}
  12x^{2} &= r^{2} + 4rs - 2s^{2}\\
  12y^{2} &= -r^{2} + 2rs + 2s^{2}\\
  12z^{2} &= r^{2} + 2s^{2}.
\end{align*}
Multiplying the equations above together (with a factor of $3$) gives
$$
  (72 xyz)^{2} = 3(r^{2} + 4rs - 2s^{2})(-r^{2}+2rs+2s^{2})(r^{2}+2s^{2}).
$$
Setting $X=\frac{r}{s}$ and $Y = \frac{72xyz}{s^{3}}$ gives
$$
Y^{2} = -3X^{6} - 6X^{5} + 30X^{4} + 60X^{2} + 24X - 24.
$$
As expected, the Jacobian of this curve has rank $1$ and Chabauty's method (implemented in Magma) shows that the only rational points on it are $(1 : \pm 9 : 1)$. It follows that every rational point on $D$ has $r = s$. The intersection of $r = s$ with the curve $D$ consists of the $8$ points $\{ (\pm 1/2 : \pm 1/2 : \pm 1/2 : 1 : 1) \}$ and this implies that $C(\mathbb{Q}) = \{ (\pm 1 : \pm 1 : 1) \}$.
Note: This technique of looking at covers was also used by Flynn and Wetherell in their 2001 Acta Arithmetica paper (titled Covering collections and a challenge problem of Serre) showing that the only rational points on $x^{4} + y^{4} = 17$ are $(\pm 2, \pm 1)$ and $(\pm 1, \pm 2)$. This question is more challenging than the OP's question.
